# How to click on the checkbox as per the HTML using Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Trying to check the checkbox with below code

```
<label class="checkboxPlainLabel" for="Quote_SensitiveDataConfirmation">
```

Comment: can you please post your exact question.

Comment: I am trying to check the checkbox which is customized. When i inspect that check box i see only <label class="checkboxPlainLabel" for="Quote_SensitiveDataConfirmation"> line

Comment: please provide bit more HTML code. So that new locators can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can click it like below code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='Quote_SensitiveDataConfirmation']")).click();
```

Hope that helps you:)

Comment: Thank you but it is not working.i too tried with many combinations of Xpath still searching for result

Comment: Please see this image " https://www.screencast.com/t/y5iDtuDGe0" ... If i use above xpath it will click terms&condition link. HTML code - https://www.screencast.com/t/rzakuLBw8CJ

Comment: what is inside the label tag. can you please expand it, and try to inspect upto the inner tag in label tag and then try to click on it. Also your first image is not displaying and saying image not found. Please attach HTML code present inside label tag and then it will not be an issue to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided to click on the *checkbox* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='Quote_SensitiveDataConfirmation']"))).click();
//or
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='Quote_SensitiveDataConfirmation']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you but its not working... please find HTML code and website design here:https://www.screencast.com/t/rzakuLBw8CJ

Comment: Can you update the main question with this formation please?